# Does Android 3.2.1 support auto-complete feature?

Tags: keyboard, 3.2-honeycomb

When I type with a keyboard in any app on my older Acer Android Tablet, I don't get any words automatically suggested (above the keyboard), although auto-correct does work. I can't find a setting for this feature either. Is this feature not supported in Android 3.2.1?

Comment: Is acer using the [Google Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latin&hl=en) application or its own? The google keyboard app can be installed from the play store and should come with this feature and always be up to date since google moved it to the playstore.

Comment: I have no proper access to Playstore (and thus - to Google keyboard) after resetting the tablet to default configuration (password authentication issue that would not go away). Interestingly before the reset, auto-suggest was working. I recall, it started working after I had installed ^some^ updates shortly after buying the tablet, but then stopped again after doing a hard reset (and now not sure how to bring it back).

Comment: No idea what went wrong there as I've never had a device manufactured by Acer. You can still give the google keyboard a shot by installing its APK file. You can download it [from here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2312179). Make sure you can enable `Installation from unknown sources` insides your `settings > security`. Then install this app and try it out ;)